# Python. AttributeError: module 'aiogram.utils' has no attribute 'keyboard'

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу импортировать ReplyKeyboardBuilder, но пишет что нету keyboard, хотя в документации все есть и все импортируется. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажи код, а то непонятно.

Comment: "В чем может быть ошибка?" - ошибка может быть в коде

Comment: не в коде дело, ошибка выдается еще на этапе импорта
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder
просто не находит keyboard в aiogram.utils, хотя быть он там должен

Comment: Ну, опечатался ты где-нибудь. Чудес-то не бывает.

Comment: ну тогда опечатался не я а тот кто делал документацию, ведь я оттуда скопировал, очевидно что опечатка это первый проверенный вариант

Comment: Какую версию Aiogram вы используете?